# How to generate bold face numbers in LaTeX as they appear in Microsoft Word or PowerPoint?

Tags: pdftex, symbols, latex-misc

In MS Word and PowerPoint you have a set of these bold faced numbers written like

[image]

More specifically
[image]

Does anyone know if you can generate these using LaTeX? It does not seem to be the output of either `mathbf`, `mathfrak`, `mathscr`

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The right command in LaTeX is `\mathbb`, but the default fonts only have blackboard bold letter, not blackboard bold numbers.

The easiest solution is to use a Opentype Math font that has blackboard bold numbers; but this requires XeTeX or LuaTeX engine. For example, in ConTeXt you can use Cambria Math font as follows:

```
\setupbodyfont[cambria]

\starttext
$\Bbb 1234567890$
\stoptext
```

[image]

In LaTeX, I believe that one can use `fontspec` package to load opentype fonts.

If you just need boldface 1, you can use `dsfont` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dsfont}

\begin{document}
$\mathds{1}$
\end{document}
```

[image]